# Entity Framework 5.0 with vs 13

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

There is an issue with my visual studio. When i try to generate the edmx file it does all the process very well. But as soon as i try to build the solution it throws so many errors. I am not sure if this issue is with visual studio orentity framework.

Please check the image i have attached, and the errors as well.
[image]

Here are the errors..

> Error 7   A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces;
> 'System' is a type not a namespace
>
> Error 73  The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

There are so many errors.

Please help

Comment: Did you added reference for dll?

Comment: yes it's all there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean contents of ".vs" folder in the root of solution